# Usage of Cauchy-Schwarz in lower bound argument

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to understand the following step in a paper which the authors claim follows by Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$
\left ( \int_D  \left( \int_D k(x,y) dx\right)^2 dy \right)^{1/2}
\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{\text{vol}(D)}} \int_{D \times D} k(x,y)dxdy
$$

I'm not seeing how Cauchy-Schwarz leads to this conclusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have
$$\begin{align*}
\int_{D \times D} k(x,y)dxdy &= \int_{D}\underbrace{\left( \int_{D} k(x,y)  dx \right)}_{f(y)} \cdot \underbrace{1}_{g(y)} dy \\&\leq \Big( \int_{D}\underbrace{\left( \int_{D} k(x,y) dx \right)^2}_{f(y)^2}  dy\Big)^{1/2}\Big( \int_{D} \underbrace{1^2}_{g(y)^2}  dy\Big)^{1/2}
\end{align*}$$
and the last factor is equal to
$$
\left( \int_{D}dy\right)^{1/2} = \sqrt{\text{vol}(D)}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Use $\int f(y) g(y) \, dy \le \left(\int (f(y))^2 \, dy\right)^{1/2} \left(\int (g(y))^2 \, dy \right)^{1/2}$ on the outer integral.

\begin{align}
&\int_{D \times D} k(x, y) \, dx \, dy
\\
&= \int_D \left(\int_D k(x, y) \, dx\right) \, dy
\\
&= \int_D 1 \cdot \left(\int_D k(x, y) \, dx\right) \, dy
\\
&\le \left(\int_D 1^2 \, dy\right)^{1/2}
\left(\int_D \left(\int_D k(x, y) \, dx\right)^2 \, dy \right)^{1/2}
\\
&= \sqrt{\text{vol}(D)}
\left(\int_D \left(\int_D k(x, y) \, dx\right)^2 \, dy \right)^{1/2}
\end{align}